# Terminology -- lying over something

Tags: terminology, algebraic-number-theory

I just came across reading something like this:

'Let $\phi\in \text{Gal}(L/K)$ lie above $Frob\in \text{Gal}(K^{un}/K)$.'

Where $Frob$ is the Frobenius automorphism and $K^{un}$ is the maximal unramified extension (which is unimportant in my question here). I know what it means for a prime ideal to lie over a prime (so say something like $\mathfrak{p}$ lies over $p\in \mathbb{Z}$), but does exactly does it mean for an automorphism $\phi$ to lie over another automorphism?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if you restrict $\phi$ to the field $K^{un}$, you get the Frobenius automorphism.